# WebDriverBackedSelenium in Internet Explorer is not working

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

An error can be seen while running the test in Selenium, I have tried removing and adding the capabilities but in vain:

```
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);

    WebDriverBackedSelenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, url);

      Thread.sleep(3000);
              selenium.open(url);
      driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
              selenium.type("userId", "TEst");
```

The error is thrown because of the line selenium.type("userId", "TEst") and the error is as follows:

```
JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 81 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15'
System info: host: 'slc05apo', ip: '10.241.115.70', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_26'
Session ID: 4368aa6a-ba4a-42a9-8428-1ce9a8f71dcc
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0,      enablePersistentHover=true, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=8, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, requireWindowFocus=false, handlesAlerts=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:39326/, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
```

But no error can be seen if I use this:

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver( DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());
driver.get(url);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("test");
```

But I want to use the first given case. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the capabilities you are setting, should be passed when instantiating the driver.
Please change this

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver( DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());
```

to

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Can you provide the URL ? if possible

Comment: I can't, its an internal one. But this issue is occurring only with our product and not any others. And as I mentioned above it works with webdriver operation but fails with WebDriverBackedSelenium operations.

Comment: Have you set the IEDriver path? Please atleast provide the `userId` html part.

Comment: Yes, I did. As I mentioned, its working with WebDriver. HTML part: <input id="userId" type="text" name="j_username" size="30" class="loginField" autocomplete="off" style="margin-left: 6px;">